# How to build Angular projects in proper order with a mono repo?

Tags: angular, build

I am having difficulties building my Angular library and triggering an Angular application to be built with the changes.

I have an Angular project that contains a library named `myLibrary` and also an application named `demo`.

When I start working on the project I'll open *two* consoles and start *two* builds.

Console one:

```sh
ng build myLibrary --watch
```

Console two:

```sh
ng serve demo --watch
```

When I make a change to the `myLibrary` project it starts a build which immediately starts a build for the `demo` application. This results in the web browser hot reloading the page, but contains *none of the changes* from the library. I have to press `F5` to refresh the page to see the changes.

I would like my builds to work in the proper sequence so that the `demo` does not start building until the library is finished.

What would be *ideal* is if `ng serve --watch` would just build *both* projects for me so that I didn't have to run two builds.

*FYI: I do not want to restart builds when files changes, because that would be much slower.*

Comment: Found this [article](https://medium.com/@ntkolev/angular-6-build-watch-multiple-dependent-libraries-in-one-shell-562a5131788c) in the comments of a similar question. Seems like it will do the trick